# pushed code to github main, but github pages got only the basic create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, github

I pushed my code to git-hub main branch and its all fine,
but the git-hub-pages got the basic "get started" react app.

did it happened to anyone??

first i pushed to code to github. than i:

install github pages : npm install gh-pages --save-dev
set "Homepage": "www.githubAccountname.github.io/reponame"; 
set "predeploy": "npm run build", 
set "deploy": "gh-pages -d build" 
than i did "npm run deploy"

and again, i got the "basic start" app, where you can see react logo in the middle

Comment: You might deployed a different branch?

Comment: github pages is always a diffrenet branch, as far as i know...